# How to build text from mixed xml content using Python?

Tags: python-3.x, xml

I have a situation in which an XML document has information in varying depth (according to S1000D schemas), and I'm looking for a generic method to extract correct sentences.

I need to interpret a simple element containing text as one individual part/sentence, and when an element that's containing text contains other elements that in turn contain text, I need to flatten/concatenate it into one string/sentence. The nested elements shall not be visited again if this is done.

Using Pythons `lxml` library and applying the `tostring` function works ok if the source XML is pretty-printed, so that I may split the concatenated string into new lines in order to get each sentence. If the source isn't pretty-printed, in one single line, there won't be any newlines to make the split.

I have tried the iter function and applying `xpaths` to each node, but this often renders other results in Python than what I get when applying the `xpath` in `XMLSpy`.

I have started down some of the following paths, and my question is if you have some input on which ones to continue on, or if you have other solutions.

I think I could use XSLT to preprocess the XML file, and then use a simpler Python script to divide the content into a list of sentence for further processing. Using Saxon with Python is now doable, but here I run into problems if the XML source contains entities that I cannot redirect Saxon to resolve (such as & nbsp;). I have no problem parsing files with `lxml`, so I tend to lean towards a cleaner Python solution.

`lxml` doesn't seem to have `xpath` support that can give me all nodes with text that contains one or more children containing text, and all nodes that are simple elements with no parents containing text nodes. Is there way to preprocess the parsed tree so that I can ensure it is pretty printed in memory, so that `tostring` works the same way for every XML file? Otherwise, my logic gives me one string for a document with no white space, and multiple sentences/strings if the source had been pretty printed. This doesn't feel ok.

What are my options? Use `XSLT 1.0` in Python, other parsers to get a better handle on where I am in the tree, ...

Just to reiterate the issue here; I am looking for a generic way to extract text, and the only rules to the XML source are that a sentence may be built from an element with child elements with text, but there won't be additional levels. The other possibility is the simple element, but this one cannot be included in a parent element with text since this is included in the first rule.

Help/thoughts are appreciated.

Comment: lxml should also have XSLT support, so you wouldn't necessarily need to use Saxon: https://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html.

Comment: Yes, I'm using xslt 1.0 extensively but figured it's time to move on :-) I have written an xslt 2.0 that accomplishes this, but it's quite slow, and as I said, I would have to process the files first in order to replace entities such as nbsp first if I want to parse with Saxon.

Comment: Is nbsp defined in your DTD? It is not a standard XML entity like lt, gt, or amp, so any XML parser should give you an error if it is not, not just Saxon's. If it is in your DTD, then I'm not sure why Saxon would have an issue: http://xsltransform.net/6qjwabw

Comment: Correct, it would not just be Saxon, but in Python I can get around this problem by making "external" entities known to the parser, and by doing this, changing the entity to a correct one, or ignoring it all together if the deleted(?) entity won't cause problems for my analyses. I can also set the lxml parser to not expand entities, and to continue on error. Both of these options can be valid, depending on what I need to pull from a document.

Comment: Hi, I would hope Saxon/C for python can help you to move forward to XSLT 2.0/3.0. Saxon does support DTDs. Can you share the example XML with the DTD please?

Comment: ond1, thanks for helping, and I will try to find a file where i get into trouble with parsing, but I guess it will be something that's not valid xml due to the use of undeclared &nbsp;. These entities seems to stem from legacy that has not been transformed correctly, but nonetheless I have to deal with them. Best is of course to correct the source files when I can, but sometimes, the source is out of my control, and I still would like to be able to process them to some extent.

Answer (score 0):

This is a downright ugly code, a hastily hack with no real thought on form, beauty or finesse. All I am after is one way of doing this in Python. I'll tidy things up when I find a good solution that I want to keep. This is one possible solution so I figured I'd post it to see if someone can be kind enough to show me how to do this instead.

The problems has been to have `xpath` expressions that could get me all elements with text content, and then to act upon the depending on their context. All my `xpath` expressions has given me the correct nodes, but also a root, or ancestor that has pulled a more or less complete string at the beginning, so I gave up on those. My `xpath` functions as they should in XSLT, but not in Python - don't know why...

I had to revert to regex to find nodes that contains strings that are not white space only.

Using `lxml` with `xpath` and `tostring` gives different results depending on how the source XML is formatted, so I had to get around that.

The following formats have been tested:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <root>
        <subroot>
            <a>Intro, element a: <b>Nested b to be included in a, <c>and yet another nested c-element</c> and back to b.</b></a>
            <!-- Comment -->
            <a>Simple element.</a>
            <a>Text with<b> 1st nested b</b>, back in a, <b>and yet another b-element</b>, before ending in a.</a>
        </subroot>
    </root>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>

    <subroot>
        <a>Intro, element a: <b>Nested b to be included in a, <c>and yet another nested c-element,

        </c> and back to b.</b>
        </a>
        <!-- Comment -->
        <a>Simple element.</a>
        <a>Text with<b> 1st nested b</b>, back in a, <b>and yet another b-element</b>, before ending in a.</a>
    </subroot>
</root>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><root><subroot><a>Intro, element a: <b>Nested b to be included in a, <c>and yet another nested c-element</c> and back to b.</b></a><!-- Comment --><a>Simple element.</a><a>Text with<b> 1st nested b</b>, back in a, <b>and yet another b-element</b>, before ending in a.</a></subroot></root>
```

Python code:

```
dmParser=ET.XMLParser(resolve_entities=False, recover=True)
xml_doc = r'C:/Temp/xml-testdoc.xml'
parsed = ET.parse(xml_doc)

for elem in parsed.xpath("//*[re:match(text(), '\S')]", namespaces={"re": "http://exslt.org/regular-expressions"}):
    tmp = elem.xpath("parent::*[re:match(text(), '\S')]", namespaces={"re": "http://exslt.org/regular-expressions"})
    if(tmp and tmp[0].text and tmp[0].text.strip()): #Two first checks can yield None, and if there is something check if only white space
        continue #If so, discard this node
    elif(elem.xpath("./*[re:match(text(), '\S')]", namespaces={"re": "http://exslt.org/regular-expressions"})): #If a child node also contains text
        line =re.sub(r'\s+', ' ',ET.tostring(elem, encoding='unicode', method='text').strip()) #Replace all non wanted whitespace 
        if(line):
            print(line)
    else: #Simple element
        print(elem.text.strip())
```

Always yields:

```
Intro, element a: Nested b to be included in a, and yet another nested c-element, and back to b.
Simple element.
Text with 1st nested b, back in a, and yet another b-element, before ending in a.
```